# Android - Cursor not properly working

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an app that inserts data into a database with 2 tables (project and alvara)
The insertion method for the second table depends on what type the first table gets. (1 or 2) for resumed idea.

This is a method that I made for looking into the second table with cursor. If it finds, it sets in setters from alvara_db class. And later on, I use getters to show info on textviews in another activity. The issue is that it's not setting info at all. Is anything wrong in my Cursor?

Thanks in advance!

```
public ArrayList<alvara_db> getAlvaras(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<alvara_db> projects = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] project = new String[]{String.valueOf(tipoprojetoid)};

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT placa, proj_exec, resp_tec, rtnum, parecer FROM alvara WHERE projetoid = ?", project);
    cur.moveToFirst();

    alvara_db alvaras = new alvara_db();
    alvaras.setPlaca(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("placa")));
    alvaras.setProj_exec(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("proj_exec")));
    alvaras.setResp_tec(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("resp_tec")));
    alvaras.setRtnum(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("rtnum")));
    alvaras.setParecer(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("parecer")));
    projects.add(alvaras);

    return projects;
}
```

Fragment where I call getAlvaras method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detalhes_projeto_alvara);
    db.getAlvaras();

    placa = alvaras.getPlaca();
    resp_tec = alvaras.getResp_tec();
    proj_exec = alvaras.getProj_exec();
    rtnum = alvaras.getRtnum();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the returned value from `db.getAlvaras()`.

Instead the `alvaras` variable in your second snippet is something that is likely not initialized - the code you posted does not show that exactly.

(In addition, you might want to check the return value of `moveToFirst()` in case the query matches no rows, and add a `do`-`while` loop to retrieve more than one row.)

Comment: @Iaalto 1- Yeah. I know that. I thought that by simply setting the info fetched from the database I could get it on the textviews. 2- It is initialized right before onCreate. Sorry for not posting it. 3- I think it won't be necessary because it will always return only one row.

Comment: @Iaalto May I get some orientation on how to use my returned value?

Comment: `ArrayList<alvara_db> alvarasList = db.getAlvaras();`

Comment: I'm planning to place the returned column values into a predefined layout. Is there any way to do this with this arraylist? using ArrayAdapter maybe?